# trying to make all parts universal fails

Tags: roblox

my code is this:

```
prt = workspace:GetChildren()
for i = prt, 1, -1 do
    prt.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
    prt.TopSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.BottomSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.LeftSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.RightSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.FrontSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.BackSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
end
```

here is the result
[start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIXZR.jpg) [end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Eep.png)
i need help now please ok

Answer (score 0):

You're not properly looping over the elements in the `prt` array. Take a look at the [Lua Manual](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.5.html) for help with `for-loops`. One way to loop over all of the objects is to use `ipairs()`

```
local parts = workspace:GetChildren()
for i, prt in ipairs(parts) do
    if not prt:IsA("BasePart") then
        continue
    end

    prt.Material = Enum.Material.Plastic
    prt.TopSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.BottomSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.LeftSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.RightSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.FrontSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
    prt.BackSurface = Enum.SurfaceType.Universal
end
```

You should be careful, `workspace:GetChildren()` gets EVERYTHING in the Workspace, including players' character models. So it might be better to organize the things that need to be changed into a Folder or something.

Comment: i want EVERY part not just the parts but thanks

Comment: This solution will work for any part that inherits from the BasePart subclass. The check at the start of the loop is to protect against trying to set the properties on objects that don't have those fields, like Lights, Scripts, or Models.